# aws step functions pass data from lambda to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I've been researching on how to pass data from a Lambda to another Lambda in a Step Function and this is what i got.
I have this dummy lambda that pass the data name:

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const name = 'test';
    callback(null, { name });
}
```

to another lambda, where i try to get the data in this way, but is not working:

```
const name = event.name; //this returns undefined
```

Based [on this tutorial](https://meetrix.io/blog/aws/07-passing-data-between-lambda-in-aws-step-function.html), this should be enough but it doesn't work. Can you point me in what direction should i go? Do i have to use the `InputPath`, `ResultPath` properties of the states machines?

[Update]
This is the State machine definition:

```
{
  "Comment": "commen test",
  "StartAt": "FunctionOne",
  "States": {
    "FunctionOne": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": <arn FunctionOne>
      },
      "Next": "FunctionTwo"
    },
    "FunctionTwo": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": <arn FunctionTwo>
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your fsm definition?

Comment: @jellycsc updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
  "Comment": "commen test",
  "StartAt": "FunctionOne",
  "States": {
    "FunctionOne": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "<arn FunctionOne>",
      "Next": "FunctionTwo"
    },
    "FunctionTwo": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "<arn FunctionTwo>",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! Do you have an explanation for the change you propose? When creating the states I used the "generate snippets" option, and print out the states with that format

Comment: You don't need a service integration to call a lambda. Please read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html#amazon-states-language-task-state-lambda) documentation.